# Adding items to Stripe invoices with PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I followed the API reference [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoice) but when I try to create and invoice, I get this error:

> missing an item

So I created some items and now I want to add an item to the invoice but I don't understand how to write it in the invoice array.

Right now I have this code. It creates the invoice but with ALL the items I created until now. How do I specify the item within the function?

```
try {

    require_once('./Stripe/init.php');
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_iP2aEsMDAc0ZCh5XGdE6AOnt");

    $customer = \Stripe\Invoice::create(array(
        "customer" => "cus_CML6eYLJif4EJ5",
        "billing" => "charge_automatically",
        "description" => "Testing invoices"
    ));

    echo 'Invoice created';
}
```

Comment: Getting your point. Need to get first all last 100 invoice & match your $charge->id  then Charge::retrieve and update description.

I have recently faced this issue.

Comment: Please explain your whole process. Before this you have subscribe plan to user.

Comment: @ravipatel I don't understand what you are telling me :/

Answer (score 0):

[More info](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_invoiceitem)

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_iP2aEsMDAc0ZCh5XGdE6AOnt");

\Stripe\InvoiceItem::create(array(
    "customer" => "cus_CML6eYLJif4EJ5",
    "amount" => 2500,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "description" => "One-time setup fee")
);
```

Comment: But there is no reference to any item created, how do we specify what item to add to the invoice?

Comment: You add the invoice items first, and then when you create the invoice they will automatically be added to it.